# Python - Import file into NamedTuple

Tags: python

Recently I had a question regarding data types.
Since then, I've been trying to use NamedTuples (with more or less success).

My problem currently:
- How to import the lines from a file to new tuples,
- How to import the values separated with space/tab(/whatever) into a given part of the tuple?

Like:

```
Monday  8:00    10:00   ETR_28135   lh1n1522    Computer science    1     
Tuesday 12:00   14:00   ETR_28134   lh1n1544    Geography EA    1
```

First line should go into tuple[0]. First data: tuple[0].day; second: tuple[0].start; ..and so on.
And when the new line starts (that's two TAB (\t), start a new tuple, like tuple[1]).

I use this to separate the data:

> ```
> with open(Filename) as f:
>     for line in f:
>         rawData = line.strip().split('\t')
> ```

And the rest of the logic is still missing (the filling up of the tuples).

(I know. This question, and the recent one are  really low-level ones. However, hope these will help others too. If you feel like it's not a real question, too simple to be a question, etc etc, just vote to close. Thank you for your understanding.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Such database files are called comma separated values even though they are not really separated by commas. Python has a handy library called `csv` that lets you easily read such files

Here is a slightly modified [example from the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#examples)

```
csv.register_dialect('mycsv', delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, 'mycsv')
```

Usually you work one line at a time. If you need the whole file in a tuple then:

```
t = tuple(reader)
```

### EDIT

If you need to access fields by name you could use [cvs.DictReader](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), but I don't know how exactly that works and I could not test it here.

### EDIT 2

Looking at what [namedtuples](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) are, I'm a bit outdated. There is a nice example on how namedtuple could work with the csv module:

```
EmployeeRecord = namedtuple('EmployeeRecord', 'name, age, title, department, paygrade')

import csv
for line in csv.reader(open("employees.csv", "rb")):
    emp = EmployeeRecord._make(line)
    print emp.name, emp.title
```

Comment: Frankly, the reader code from the post is OK. The question was about named tuples, which this answer sort of misses.

Comment: The namedtuple part is not really working here, but trying to figure the problem out.

Comment: @Shiki: it is strange. once you had a reader and created a namedtuple class just iter the reader and call `_make` for each line.

Comment: I know you already done a lot, but could you be more specific? How do you do that here?

Comment: @Shiki: I don't know even which is your problem with namedtuple, did you imported from `collections`? `from collections import namedtuple`. Then create the tuple subclass: `MyRecord = namedtuple('MyRecord', ['day,', 'start', 'and so on', '...'])` and then just call its `_make` method: `for line in reader: line = MyRecord._make(line); print line.day, line.start

Answer (score 3):

Here's a compact way of doing such things.
First declare the class of line item:

```
fields = "dow", "open_time", "close _time", "code", "foo", "subject", "bar"
Item = namedtuple('Item', " ".join(fields))
```

The next part is inside your loop.

```
# this is what your raw data looks like after the split:
#raw_data = ['Monday', '8:00', '10:00', 'ETR_28135', 'lh1n1522', 'Computer science', '1']
data_tuple = Item(**dict(zip(fields, raw_data)))
```

Now slowly:

- `zip(fields, raw_data)` creates a list of pairs, like `[("dow", "Monday"), ("open_time", "8:00"),..]`
- then `dict()` turns it into a dictionary, like `{"dow": "Monday", "open_time": "8:00", ..}`
- then `**` interprets this dictionary as a bunch of keyword parameters to `Item` constructor, an equivalent of `Item(dow="Monday", open_time="8:00",..)`.

So your items are named tuples, with all values being strings.

**Edit:**

If order of fields is not going to change, you can do it far easier:

```
data_tuple = Item(*raw_data)
```

This uses the fact that order of fields in the file and order of parameters in `Item` definition match.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a NamedTuple, you can use a slightly modified version of the example given in the Python documentation:

```
MyRecord = namedtuple('MyRecord', 'Weekday, start, end, code1, code2, title, whatever')

import csv
for rec in map(MyRecord._make, csv.reader(open("mycsv.csv", "rb"), delimiter='\t')):
    print rec.weekday
    print rec.title
    # etc...
```